# Keyboard not working in Windows 10 Apps + Start Menu

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently updated to Windows 10 anniversary update and recentlly noticed the PS/2 Keyboard has stopped working in Windows 10 apps such as the settings menu and the start menu. Desktop apps and control panel work fine including shortcuts buttons such as volume up, web browser etc.

The default driver installed seems to be Lenovo ThinkPad driver PS/2 keyboard (which the keyboard Is not). I uninstalled the driver, un-plugged keyboard and tried changing the driver to the standard driver and HID keyboard driver with no luck.

How can I get the keyboard to work in the Windows 10 app section?

Comment: This sounds like a hardware failure.  My PS/2 keyboard has no problems on my system

Comment: @Ramhound Possibly but I don’t understand why it works for the desktop section. I thought it could be a driver or security issue between the keyboard and Win 10 Metro Section.

Comment: The chances of it being a driver problem, is very unlikely, PS/2 driver hasn't changed in years.  Have you tried a different keyboard?

Comment: @Ramhound - I was having the same issue, the keyboard works fine in other apps, but just not for the start menu or built-in windows 10 apps like the calculator.

Comment: @Tasgall If the keyboard works then it literally cannot be a driver problem

Comment: @Ramhound - it also means it can't be a keyboard hardware problem. The answer to run ctfmon.exe fixed the issue for me, so it looks like an OS issue.

Comment: I've had success with restarting Windows Explorer from the Task Manager.

Comment: None of the answers on this post fixed it for me :'(

Answer (score 80):

If you are still stuck try this simplest of the solution.

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (to open Run )
2. Copy paste and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run this program. `C:\Windows\system32\ctfmon.exe`. It brings back the language bar and for me it allowed me to type in Windows search, start menu and Windows 10 apps again.

I think it is due to the missing language bar or something like that.

Comment: Wow, this worked for me. Now start menu reacts to keyboard again!. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there a (preferred) way to ensure that `ctfmon.exe` runs on system startup? I can run it and the problem goes away but only until I reboot.

Comment: This is - at least for me - only a temporary fix which works until the next reboot

Comment: In my case the CTF Loader was called by the Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel Service (TabletInputService), which was disabled because I am not using a tablet. Setting that to manual and then re-enabling Microsoft/Windows/TextServicesFramework/MsCtfMonitor  in the Task Scheduler Library did the trick. If that does not work, try setting it to automatic. But I think manual (triggered) is the way it is supposed to work.

Comment: @Daniel Williams 2020 here, still facing the issue, guess they are focusing more on pushing bloatware using windows updates rather than working on actual issues.

Comment: Permanent solution: https://superuser.com/questions/1532209/what-causes-the-msctfmonitor-scheduled-task-to-be-deleted-in-windows-10-causing

Answer (score 49):

I had the same problem. This is what worked for me:

1. Open `Task manager`.
2. Find `Cortana` (or `SearchUI`/`Search`) on the `Processes` tab
3. Right click it - `End task`

Comment: The funniest thing is, this is the worst rated answer on this post but it did solve my problem.

Comment: Seems like Cortana is having a bit o'fun with my keyboard.

Comment: This just worked for me as well - zas' answer had no effect.

Comment: "SearchUI.exe" on the details tab in task manager

Comment: If killing the process doesnt work, then restart the "Windows Search" service. From task manager, `File-->Run` then open `cmd.exe` with admin priv (checkbox). In the window that pops up, type `sc stop WSearch` and hit enter, then type `sc start WSearch`  and hit enter

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I couldn't find Cortana in Processes tab, but based on the comments, looked for SearchUI.exe and killed it (it was in Suspended state at that time). Saved me from rebooting/logout-login.

Comment: This is - at least for me - only a temporary fix which works until the next reboot

Comment: I killed "CTF Loader" process and start working again

Comment: so combining this with zas's answer worked for me

Comment: I tried Cortana but it didnt work. It worked with Search (not SearchUI). It works because Search restarts after you end it as a task (might add this info at the answer)

Comment: This worked in lieu of my prior method of Restarting Windows Explorer.

Comment: It worked. I wonder how long does it take for Microsoft to fix this. The issue was shipped with Windows 8...

Comment: This was the solution for me.

Answer (score 11):

I solved the problem by ending the "search" process in task manager. (I have cortana disabled)

Comment: This was my problem as well. cftmon.exe and killing cortana did not work.

Answer (score 4):

Found this solution that worked for me:

http://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/64757-keyboard-does-not-work-windows-store-apps.html

(Win+R > taskschd.msc > Task Scheduler Library > Microsoft > Windows > TextServicesFramework. Right click MsCtfMonitor and choose Enable. Reboot your PC.)

Comment: You can just right click Run after clicking Enable as well. Also make sure that the Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel Service (TabletInputService) is available.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers worked for me, so I simply opened Task Manager, killed explorer.exe (Task Manager - Details - locate explorer.exe and kill it) and run it again (Task Manager - File - Run new task - type "explorer").

Comment: ...and if Explorer isn't showing the Task Manager processes list, open any folder, then it will.