# What causes the MsCtfMonitor scheduled task to be deleted in Windows 10, causing the keyboard to stop working?

Tags: windows-10

I have repeatedly hit an issue with Windows 10 where the keyboard stops working in the start menu. It is [this issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1125367/keyboard-not-working-in-windows-10-apps-start-menu) with the important difference that the `MsCtfMonitor` scheduled task is not just not running but missing entirely:

[image]

The fix for this is to XML export the task on a working Windows 10 installation and import it where it is missing. This is documented on the web.

Now, I have hit this issue on multiple Windows installations. It is not a one-off bug. I had it even inside of virtual machines which are, supposedly, quite clean and "ordinary" Windows installations.

Right now, I hit this on a physical computer after rebooting. There were no Windows updates recently.

What could I be doing wrong to cause this task to be deleted? What might trigger this bug?

Comment: did you install kmspico?

Comment: @NONONONONO is that software known to cause this?

Comment: Somebody I know may have installed it and in the next boot, he had this issue. Uninstalling did not help.

Comment: @NONONONONO thank you.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem, and I suspect that the cause was Avira "security" suit, which applies some "repairs" to the register. I ran it, and after a reboot, had some problems, like some programs failed to initiate automatically after startup, including the ctf loader, and it was also absent on the task scheduler.

Comment: Steps to disable extreme Avira protections: Avira Free Antivirus -> Modules -> Real-Time Protection -> Gear wheel (on top right corner) -> General -> Security -> disable "Protect files and registry entries from manipulation"

Answer (score 6):

This may be caused by installing (potentially a software like kmspico).

To fix:

Windows + R
Type regedit and enter.

Go to:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Right click on Run and add String

name it `ctfmon` and add value `C:\Windows\System32\ctfmon.exe`

After reboot that service will be up and you should not have that problem.